# Reshape data based on difference of the two columns years

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

I would like to reshape the data based on two columns i.e start year and end year like a panel data. With reshaping, I can melt based on two unique id columns but it is a little tricky. I would like to expand it lengthwise based on the difference and add a column called change (indicating 1 for the first year and 0 otherwise). Any suggestions?

Here is the format of the df.

```
A <- c("xyz", "xyz", "x","x","x", "y")
start <- c("2001", "1999", "2001", "2000", "1998", "2001")
end <- c("2002", "2001", "2002", "2001", "2000", "2001")
df<- data.frame(A, start,end)
```

I would like to final data as follows

```
  A     year   change
 xyz    2001     1
 xyz    2002     0
 xyz    1999     1
 xyz    2000     0
 x      2001     1
 x      2002     0
 x      2000     1
 x      2001     0
 x      1998     1
 x      1999     0
 x      2000     0
 y      2001     1
```

Comment: 'library(reshape2)
melt(df,id=c("A"))'

Comment: I tried the library splitstackshape to expand based on the differences <- end-year but i was not getting the panel data.

Comment: You could try `data.frame(A = rep(df[, 1], each = 2), year = c(t(df[-1])), change = 1:0)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg I don't think that matches the intended output since there is only 1 row of `y` and `x` has to cover the `year 1999`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about:

```
### OP's code
A <- c("xyz", "xyz", "x","x","x", "y")
start <- c("2001", "1999", "2001", "2000", "1998", "2001")
end <- c("2002", "2001", "2002", "2001", "2000", "2001")
df<- data.frame(A, start,end)

### cast the variables start and end to integer in df
start<-as.integer(start)
end  <-as.integer(end)
df   <-data.frame(A, start, end, stringsAsFactors=F)

### Build up the required columns
expand_year<-with(df, mapply(seq,start,end))
expand_A <- rep(df$A,sapply(expand_year,length))
change<-sapply(expand_year,function(x){ c(1,rep(0,length(x)-1)) })

### Put all the columns into a data.frame
final<-data.frame(A=expand_A,
              year=unlist(expand_year),
              change=unlist(change))
```

Output:

```
> final
     A year change
1  xyz 2001      1
2  xyz 2002      0
3  xyz 1999      1
4  xyz 2000      0
5  xyz 2001      0
6    x 2001      1
7    x 2002      0
8    x 2000      1
9    x 2001      0
10   x 1998      1
11   x 1999      0
12   x 2000      0
13   y 2001      1
```

Comment: Awesome!! Great solution :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the package "reshape2":

```
library(reshape2)
df <- melt(df, id = "A")
```

We now have an ID column, a variable column indicating whether the observation is from a "start" or an "end" year, and a value column giving that gives the year corresponding to each "start" and "end" associated with each ID.

The "change" variable that you describe is functionally equivalent to the variable column produced by melting the original data frame. We can replicate it more explicitly by assigning a value of 1 to "start" observations and a value of 0 to "end" observations.

```
df$change <- 0
df$change[df$variable == "start"] <- 1
```